# OAuth authentication for magiccardmarket with Python requests

Tags: python, api, oauth, python-requests

I want to programmatically fetch the stock of specific users on http://www.cardmarket.com/, but can't seem to get OAuth authentication to work in the following Python snippet.

Simply using available methods from the requests_oauthlib library have not given any positive results and I've also tried constructing the OAuth header myself and passing that along in the requests-call, all to no avail. I'm a bit at the end of my wits, because I've tried for hours without results, to the point where I've lost most enjoyment for what should have been a simple hobby project. Nonetheless I'm confident that it's a simple problem that can hopefully be resolved quickly.

Here's the simple code that should, but doesn't, work:

```py
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

user = ..

app_token  = ..
app_secret = ..
access_token = ..
access_token_secret = ..

request_url = "https://api.cardmarket.com/ws/v2.0/users/" + user + "/articles?start=0&maxResults=100"

auth = OAuth1(app_token, app_secret, resource_owner_key=access_token, resource_owner_secret=access_token_secret)
response = requests.get(request_url, auth=auth)    

print(response.request.headers)
print(response)
print(response.content)
```

I've also tried a mixture of variations to it and as stated, have also tried to construct the header myself, but with no results.

I don't see anything wrong with the provided code as-is, but still get an error for being unauthorized when performing the given query.

The response.request.headers print statement returns the following:

```
{'Authorization': b'OAuth oauth_nonce="..", oauth_timestamp="..", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="..", oauth_token="..", oauth_signature=".."', 'Accept-Encoding': b'gzip, deflate', 'User-Agent': b'python-requests/2.18.4', 'Accept': b'*/*', 'Connection': b'keep-alive'}
```

Which seems the include all relevant data (though maybe too much? Things like Accept-Encoding, User-Agent and Connection are automatically added, but may not be expected, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: *"why the simple code given above doesn't work."*: Compared with the given `cardmarket` documentation you use much less parameter. Relevant [Working Example PHP with libcurl Library ](https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/documentation/API:Auth_libcurl)

Comment: The OAuth object generates the rest of the parameters when it is called by requests.get. The nonce, timestamp, version, signature_method and signature are all generated by it. EDIT: I've included the header generated by the OAuth call in my original post.

Comment: Compared with your `response.request.headers` found missing `realm="https://api.cardmarket.com/ws/v1.1/account"`

Comment: Adding that and also sorting the keys in the header didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question**: fetch the stock of specific users

#### Cardmarket RESTful API Documentation (Version 2.0)

- [OAuth Header and Generating a Signature](https://api.cardmarket.com/ws/documentation/API:Auth_OAuthHeader)
- [Articles](https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/documentation/API_2.0:Articles)
- [User Articles](https://www.mkmapi.eu/ws/documentation/API_2.0:User_Articles)

#### Python wrapper for the cardmarket.com API (version 2.0, using OAuth1)

- [`pymkm`](https://github.com/andli/pymkm)

#### Requests-OAuthlib: OAuth for Humans

- [Docs » Requests-OAuthlib](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

---

Using `OAuth1Session`:

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

# base_url = 'https://api.cardmarket.com/ws/v2.0/output.json'
base_url = 'https://api.cardmarket.com/ws/v2.0'

# product_id = 266361 # Mandatory
# url = '{}/articles/{}'.format(base_url, product_id)

user_id = 266361 # Mandatory  Type: integer (ID) or string (name)
url = '{}/users/:{}/articles'.format(base_url, user_id)

oauth = OAuth1Session('app_token',
                       client_secret='app_secret',
                       resource_owner_key='access_token',
                       resource_owner_secret='access_token_secret',
                       realm=url
                      )

params = {'start':0, 'maxResults':100}
r = oauth.get(url, params=params)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Indeed, OAuth1Session seems to work, though I'm still left wondering why my original code didn't work.. But at least thanks for showing me this, I was able to get it working through your hints!

Comment: Fair enough, in that case, could you maybe clarify the difference in OAuth1 and OAuth1Session? Your suggestion indeed works, so I've accepted it (but sadly don't have voting privileges).

Comment: @Knaapje: *" the difference"*: Look at [oauth1_workflow.html](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth1_workflow.html) there you see `OAuth1` and `OAuth1Session` together. I assume, if you use `realm=` and `params=` as shown in my answer and indeed `auth=`, `OAuth1` will work also.