# immobilienscout24 perform Two-legged OAuth Python

Tags: python, api

i have been trying to perform Two-legged OAuth at : https://rest.immobilienscout24.de/restapi/api/ . I am following these [instructions](https://api.immobilienscout24.de/useful/authentication/authentication-detailed.html) but i am receiving 401 error code. 
Here is my code :

```
import requests

URL = "https://rest.immobilienscout24.de/restapi/api/"

consumer_key = 'ImmobilieAnalyseKey'

PARAMS = {'consumer_key': consumer_key}

r = requests.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)



print(r)
```

I have tried this and it is returning 200 but i am not getting how can i get data with two legged.

```
from rauth import OAuth1Session

consumer_key = 'xxxxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxxxx'
base_url = 'https://rest.immobilienscout24.de/restapi/api/'


def test_get():
    url = base_url
    client = OAuth1Session(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
    r = client.get(url)
    print(r)

test_get()
```

EDIT : 
ERROR RESPONSE :

```
<common:messages xmlns:common="http://rest.immobilienscout24.de/schema/common/1.0">
    <message>
        <messageCode>ERROR_BAD_REQUEST</messageCode>
        <message>Missing signature method.</message>
    </message>
</common:messages>
```

Comment: What is `rauth`? [Edit] your question and show the response error message: `print(r.text)`

Comment: @stovfl i have added response . Well i found about rauth here : https://github.com/litl/rauth it's : A simple Python OAuth 1.0/a, OAuth 2.0, and Ofly consumer library built on top of Requests.

Comment: ***`Missing signature method.`***: This error message indicates, `rauth` is incompatible with `/rest.immobilienscout24.de`. Try this approach: [oauth-authentication-with-python-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55659823/oauth-authentication-for-magiccardmarket-with-python-requests/55665510)

Comment: @stovfl yes you were right , i got it . thank you very much